# Python: Get digital signiture information for a file

Tags: python, digital-signature

I'm looking to utilize Python to create a script that checks the Digital Signatures and Copyright information for a specified file once it has been installed.

Does anyone have any ideas? I have triedusing win32file.GetFileAttributes and other such methods but I don't get the information I am looking for.

Ideally, I'd like as much from the digital signature as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: what kind of information do you want?

Comment: I'd like as much information from the digital signature as is possible. Signer information, version, serial number, valid from, valid to

Comment: Wether this is possible depends on the file format and type of signature used. Python has several libraries that can verify different kinds of signatures. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CAPICOM interfaces through win32com to get signature info from a binary executable.  These libraries aren't usually installed by default, but it's a [free download from MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=860EE43A-A843-462F-ABB5-FF88EA5896F6&amp;displaylang=e&displaylang=en).

Here's an example of how to use CAPICOM in python:

```
import win32com.client
s=win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('capicom.signedcode',0)
s.FileName=r'J:\Program Files\Adobe\Flash Player\AddIns\airappinstaller\airappinstaller.exe'
signer = s.Signer
print (signer.Certificate.IssuerName, signer.Certificate.SerialNumber)
```

Comment: I tried installing the CAPICOM SDK and executing the code but it fails:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.py", line 23, in <module>
    s=win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('capicom.signedcode',0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 529, in
 EnsureDispatch
    disp = win32com.client.Dispatch(prog_id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in
Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,c
lsctx)

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 108, in
_GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 85, in _
GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.II
D_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)

Comment: Sorry, hit enter by mistake.  Use "regsvr32 capicom.dll" at the command prompt to register it yourself.

Comment: @RogerUpole, Hi, Roger, I tried as what you suggested. register the capicom.dll and it prompted to me success. But when I ran in python, it still tell the the same error such as "(-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)" My OS is win7 x64, python version is 2.7. Any more comments? thx.